# Convert Tempdata of byte array to base64string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am doing following to convert Tempdata to ToBase64String but it showing me error. My tempdata have Byte Array.

Code on razor view:

```
var img = Convert.ToBase64String(TempData["Image"]);
```

Error:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])' 
has some invalid arguments
```

I don't know what's the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all u need to convert that `TempData["Image"]` into byte. So try this and let me know whether it is working for u or not..

```
 var img = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])TempData["Image"]);
```